# Identity server 4- Programmatically create clients & resources using the config

Tags: database, updates, identityserver4

I follow [this](https://www.scottbrady91.com/Identity-Server/Getting-Started-with-IdentityServer-4) tutorial from Scott which worked, until the point when I change in my Config file some user details but those are never update in my database.

What should I do in order that all my changes from my config file to be updated in my database as well?

[Here is InitializeDbTestData(app) method](https://github.com/scottbrady91/IdentityServer4-Example/blob/60144a22bb2abc1c51129741780726cc91af9ebd/src/ScottBrady91.IdentityServer4.Example/Startup.cs#L60)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For others who are interested in this topic you should take a look [here](https://github.com/scottbrady91/IdentityServer4-Example/issues/4)

Apparently there is no way to do this just to use other tools such as AdminUI(which you have to pay for it)